# calling a function from dialogclass

Tags: java, android

This is my **DialogClass**

```
public android.app.Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface argo0, int arg1) {
            switch (arg1){

                case 0:
                    selection=(String) items[arg1];
                    break;
                case 1:
                    selection=(String) items[arg1];
                    break;
                case 2:
                    selection=(String) items[arg1];
                    break;
                case 3:
                    selection=(String) items[arg1];
                    break;
                case 4:
                    selection=(String) items[arg1];
                    break;
                case 5:
                    selection=(String) items[arg1];
                    break;
            }
        }
    }).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Camera2BasicFragment q= new Camera2BasicFragment();
            q.c();

        }
    });
    return builder.create();
    // return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
}
}
```

I am calling a function c from parent class Camera2BasicFragment, but its returning an error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'android.graphics.SurfaceTexture 
com.example.android.camera2basic.AutoFitTextureView.getSurfaceTexture()' on 
a null object reference
```

How do you call a function inside a dialogclass???

Error occurs in the line
    SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();

of the class c

```
public void c() {

    try {
        SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        assert texture != null;

        // We configure the size of default buffer to be the size of camera preview we want.
        texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());

        // This is the output Surface we need to start preview.
        Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
```

Comment: did you properly initialize `mTextureView `?

Comment: place the code where you initialize `mTextureView`

Comment: mtextureview is Initialized here  
`public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view.findViewById(R.id.picture).setOnClickListener(this);
        view.findViewById(R.id.info).setOnClickListener(this);
        mTextureView = (AutoFitTextureView) view.findViewById(R.id.texture);
    }`

Comment: This is AutoFitTextureView class
`public class AutoFitTextureView extends TextureView {

    private int mRatioWidth = 0;
    private int mRatioHeight = 0;

    public AutoFitTextureView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public AutoFitTextureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public AutoFitTextureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }`